# iPhone pushViewController different instances of the same class

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

my problem is the following: I have a NavigationController that contains the whole app and I want to push two instances of the same UIViewController subclass, however when I call pushViewController, nothing happens. Is this behavior supported or? I use a class, that takes its arguments with the -init method and populates a UITableView programmatically based on this info.

The reason I want two instances of the same class is that I need the back button to work as expected.

The class is basically a custom UITableView that loads its content after performing an XPath query through an XML.

I will provide more information if requested.

Comment: why u want to push two instances of same class at a same time? can u just put some code snippets?

Comment: the snippet will be huge: the class instances perform XPath queries to get their contents and then arrange it in a UITableView subclass. When the user interacts with a row, it loads the next instance.

Comment: It would help if you actually stated the problem you are having with using those two instances. I never had any problem doing so in the past, do you get any kind of an error?

Comment: pushing two copies of the same controller and the same data just because you think that's the way to solve the "back button" issue sounds suspect

Comment: It is not the same instance, I was just worried that they are of the same class. Anyway, the problem was elsewhere (as predicted in comments) - I was sending pushViewController to nil instead of the UINavigationController I wanted to send to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be nothing special about pushing two distinct instances of the same VC, so long as they are, in fact, ***distinct*** instances with no UI-related objects shared between them.  (Obviously, sharing data sources, etc, is not a problem.)

Comment: agreed.  Sounds like you want two instances, but you're pushing the same instance twice.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was asking. I got some sort of error and I assumed it is because I'm pushing an instance of the same class. Now I know this is not the problem.